# Java: Listener for when *any* class is created?

Tags: java, class, constructor, runtime, listener

I'd like to be notified when *any* class is created.

For example, I'd like to setup a listener like the following pseudocode:

```
addListener("onAnyClassCreated", myCallback);

public void function myCallback(Object obj)
{
  trace("obj was just created:" + obj.toString());
}
```

and then for *any* class created by the JVM for my app, the above "myCallback" function would be called. I could manage this for my own code, but I want it to work with any 3rd party libraries I'm using as well.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What about objects created in your myCallback function? I can see at least two.  How will you avoid infinite recursion? Is there any reason you would not use a profiler to do this?

Comment: Your request is very strange, but I guess you can do this with aspect oriented programming.

Comment: I'm dubious that there's any way to do this, except maybe with JVM instrumentation?

Comment: I'm interested in tracking threads and other resources that are allocated outside of my context.... and potentially visualizing it.... but I think the concept itself could be used in lots of unforseen ways....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use profiling for counting the instances of certain class or if you really want to do what you've described, it can be done using some instrumentation tool. For instance [Byteman](https://www.jboss.org/byteman).

Comment: The listener would have to avoid creating objects which call the listener again. ;)

Comment: Using Byteman does not actually require modifying the existing code and you can't instrument the instrumentation tool itself. So there is no risk of infinite recursion as you described above. Check this guide for more info http://downloads.jboss.org/byteman/2.1.2/ProgrammersGuideSinglePage.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to achieve may be done by remotely supervising your JVM. A classic way to do it is using [Java Management Extensions (JMX)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html).

You can use an existing JMX client such as [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) or [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/). You can also create your own if you have specific needs.